# How to initialize member object when parameters aren't available at time of initializer list?

Tags: c++, class, constructor, initialization

Current structure is something like

```
class B {
  //no default constructor
  //this is a class in a third-party library, can't be modified
  B(Lots ofData, AndOther arguments);
}

class A {
  B b;

  A(some_parameters){
     //Do a lot of stuff with those parameters, make Results
     B b(Results, Results); //ERROR
  }
}
```

So, I need to call the constructor on `B`, but I don't have the information early enough to do it in the initializer list. How do I call the constructor on `B` later? Because `B` doesn't have a trivial constructor, I can't exactly initialize with some dumb defaults and overwrite it later, either.

I can't change the `B` class.

Comment: What compilation error are you getting?

Comment: @Bill the above code (almost) compiles, but it declares `b` twice. I was trying to illustrate what I would like to do (if it didn't redeclare it). It doesn't actually compile, because `B` has no default constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `B` has a copy/move constructor, you could simply make a function that returns you a `B` and use that to initialize the member like so:

```
B makeB(some_parameters) {
    //Do a lot of stuff with those parameters, make Results
    return B(Results, Results);
}

class A {
    B b;

    A(some_parameters)
      : b(makeB(some_parameters))
    {
    }
};
```

If copying/moving a `B` into your member is not an option, then one simple solution would be to just allocate the `B` object dynamically. That way you could move all the "lots of stuff, make Results" into a function

```
#include <memory>

std::unique_ptr<B> makeB(some_parameters) {
    //Do a lot of stuff with those parameters, make Results
    return std::make_unique<B>(Results, Results);
}

class A {
    std::unique_ptr<B> b;

    A(some_parameters)
      : b(makeB(some_parameters))
    {
    }
};
```

If you want your `B` to live directly inside the `A` object, you could use an [`std::optional<B>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) or an unnamed union in which you emplace the object at a later point:

```
#include <memory>

class A {
    union {
        B b;
    };

    A(some_parameters) {
        //Do a lot of stuff with those parameters, make Results
        new (&b) B(Results, Results);
    }

    ~A() {  // this is only needed if B has a non-trivial destructor
        b.~B();
    }
};
```

Comment: Why does your first solution require dynamic memory? Couldn't `makeB` return a `B`, not `unique_ptr<B>`, and still initialize the member `b` exactly as shown?

Comment: Yes, assuming that `B` has a copy/move constructor, it could. I assumed that it doesn't have those, as I would have expected that solution to be so obvious that there would be no need to ask the question…but it should probably be added to the answer for completeness' sake…

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative in C++11 is delegating constructor, something similar to:

```
Result foo(Parameters some_parameters)
{
    //Do a lot of stuff with those parameters, make Results
}

class A
{
    B b;
public:    
    A(Parameters some_parameters) : A(foo(some_parameters)){}

private:
    A(Result result) : b(Results, Results) {}
};
```